# Parse Push Notification does not work if app not in background or foreground.

Tags: android, parse-platform

All worked fine with parse push notification. When I am trying to implement a custom push notifier it works only if my app is in foreground or background.

Specifically on Lollipop this happens.

Looking forward for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go with Parse as its going to shutdown in early 2017. I would suggest you to use other Push Platform like OneSignal Push notification OR Urban Airship.

Regarding custom push notifier, can you please explain more what all things you are customizing in push notification message.